# Low Spec Computer Normal Baking Tips?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, normal-map, optimization

I'm doing the quick normal bake from high to low poly for a 300K vert mesh, but my system is struggling to keep up with the higher poly mesh.

My inclination was to do some dyntopo sculpting and alteration in the higher poly in order to achieve the finer details before texturing.

I believe I don't have any pre-render optimization settings set. Oftentimes when I undo (something I do often when sculpting), the wait for the undo result is between 10-30 seconds, and thus throws off the pace.

Any way for lower spec computers to better handle higher poly meshes, particularly in sculpt mode?

[image]

Comment: Take a look a Zacharias Rienheart's high resolution sculpting in blender video

Answer (score 1):

Blender is genereally faster if you do not view the UVs of a high poly object while at the same time working with the mesh in 3d. UV mapping a high poly object might not be necessary, it is better to avoid doing that at all and work with UVs only on the lower poly versions that you bake the normals for. You can also hide parts of the mesh while working - in edit mode <kbd>h</kbd> to hide selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to hide unselected, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to unhide. You can hide objects you do not need to see in the object mode as well it might be easier to do this from the Outliner or use local mode(<kbd>Numpad /</kbd>) to concentrate on one object. Spliting your object into smaller objects where possible and working on parts at a time might also make a difference. Obviously viewing objects in textured or material modes is slower than in solid or wireframe modes.

It's worth considering that the best cure for slow hardware might still be upgrading the hardware - no matter how much we don't want to hear that. If it's earning you money it's worth it, if not, than do you really need to work with such high poly meshes or is it possible to settle for less?..